# Is it resource-heavy to create a new array literal inside a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have always had this question in mind. Does it use many resources if I create an array literal in a function and return it, and use this function in a for loop?

For example, I have:

```
function getArray(in) {
  const array = [];
  in.forEach(element => {
      if (element.value === 'hello') {
        array.push(element);
      }
  });
  return array;
}

for (const value of outerArray) {
  const array = getArray(value.nestedArray);
  array.forEach(element => { console.log('world'); });
}
```

Here the `outerArray` contains a group of values. Each value has a nestedArray. In this example I am creating a new array literal inside the loop. And assume that `outerArray` has 9999 values and I use this loop 10 times a second. Would that use insane amount of memory? Would it be better if I create a new array in the value of `outerArray` and directly manipulate the array in that function? Like this:

```
class Value {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.displayArray = [];
  }
...
}

function getArray(value) {
  value.nestedArray.forEach(element => {
      if (element.value === 'hello') {
        value.displayArray.push(element);
      }
  });
  return array;
}

for (const value of outerArray) {
  getArray(value);
  value.displayArray.forEach(element => { console.log('world'); });
}
```

Comment: "*Would it be better if I create a new array in the value of outerArray*" - I don't see how this would make a difference, you're still creating arrays?

Comment: Just always use `for … of` syntax, don't use `.forEach`.

Comment: @Bergi The second way I only create the array once when I create the values. But the first one I need to create the array literal many times a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it use many resources if I create an array literal in a function and return it, and use this function in a for loop?

No, the new arrays should be garbage-collected regularly. So yes, of course it does use some memory, but not an "insane amount". However, how much "many" is and whether it is too much, you need to try out. Write a version of the code that doesn't create the arrays - if that is possible - and profile their memory usages.

```
function forEachHello(arr) {
  for (const element of arr) {
    if (element.value === 'hello') {
      callback(element);
    }
  }
}

for (const value of outerArray) {
  forEachHello(value.nestedArray, element => { console.log('world'); });
}
```

> Would it be better if I create a new array in the value of outerArray and directly manipulate the array in that function?

That uses even more memory, given all of the arrays exist all of the time, but it puts less pressure on the garbage collector of course. Make sure to empty the arrays when you don't need their contents any more. It might be more efficient overall, but the only way to find out is a benchmark.

Comment: Wouldn't be `return in.filter(e => e.value === 'hello')` be even less expensive?

Comment: @baao no, that creates a new array just as well; I'd expect no difference.

Comment: So the goal is to avoid creating new arrays at all ?? I worry about the garbage collector because I can imagine it kicks in very often if there are too many arrays. I have this code in many places in my project. I have a hunch this would be a very common thing in design so I ask here before I do some deeper profiling.

Comment: @newguy If you are worried about the garbage collector, then yes the goal is to create zero new objects. I wasn't sure what your application requirements are, 10k values at 10/s didn't sound very problematic (animations at 60 fps sometimes use even more entities). I read "resources" to primarily refer to "memory", not something like jitter avoidance.

Comment: @Bergi I am developing a real time game. I avoid creating new objects in animation. This function is used in network update loop so it is still resource-heavy.